# Getting permission denied error while copying files to resource bundle using run script in build phase

Tags: ios, shell, xcode4, xcode4.5, xcode5

I am trying to copy certain files to my app's resource bundle using the run script build phase in XCODE5.

I am avoiding to use copy files build phase, as I would like to copy all the files in a particular folder in one go.

I was first testing to copy just one file:

> cp "${SRCROOT}/RetaliSense/Default_Resource/Mylogo.png"
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/{PRODUCT_NAME}.app"

But I am getting this error:

> Cp:
>   /Users/DPS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RetaliSense-baptfuxnuenrneanatjvvlcmnphi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Mylogo.png:
>   Permission denied

How do I fix this?

Comment: You probably wanted to say `${PRODUCT_NAME}` instead of `{PRODUCT_NAME}`.

Comment: That's looking like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use,

> cp "${SRCROOT}/RetaliSense/Default_Resource/Mylogo.png" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/**$**{PRODUCT_NAME}.app"

instead of,

> cp "${SRCROOT}/RetaliSense/Default_Resource/Mylogo.png" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/{PRODUCT_NAME}.app"